# Symfony routing yml file

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I want to use symfony routing as standalone routing for my project, I have the following structure:

```
 app
 |--project
 |----controller
 |------catalog
 |--------category.php
 |--config
 |----routes.yml
 |--bootstrap
 |----application.php
```

inside category.php I have a class named Category, that has a method named index().
The router is called from boostrap\application.php

How would can I specify the path to the category file in the routes.yml?
Right now it look like below

```
search:
    path: /search
    defaults: { _controller: 'app\project\controller\catalog\category\category::index' }
```

Comment: try Use Namespaces and use a callable action e.g `indexAction()`

Answer (score 1):

Loading files is not the responsibility of the routing component. This component is just used to match routes to functions inside a class.

If you want classes to be found, you can use two methods:

- add an autoloader which loads the specified classes
- Follow PSR-0 (with namespaces matching the filenames and directory structure) and use composer's classloader.

I'd suggest to use the second way. This is the standard in PHP, and you're probably already using the autoloader if you fetched the routing component trough composer.

Comment: I am actually loading the files with PSR-4